# Blazor: Validation does not trigger on class instances in the model

Tags: c#, .net, validation, blazor, blazor-hybrid

I have a blazor EditForm tied to a model.

The model for example is StudentModel which has other class instantiated like lets say Phone.

```
public class Student
{
  [Required]
  public string Name {get; set;}
  
  public Phone Phone {get; set;}
}

public class Phone
{
  [Required]
  public string Number {get; set;}
}
```

When validation runs on the form, the Name in the model does get validated, but the Number property on the Phone class does not. Why? How do I get properties validated that are in other classes but are instantiated in the model?

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown how you have set up your form, but I imagine it is something like this:

```
<EditForm Model="@Model">
  <DataAnnotationsValidator />

  @*Working*@
  <InputText @bind-Value="@Model.Name" /> 

  @*Not Working*@
  <InputText @bind-Value="@Model.Phone.Number" />
</EditForm>

@code {
  private Student Model {get; set;} = new();
}
```

If you want to validated nested complex properties, instead of using

`<DataAnnotationsValidator />`

you can use

`<ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator />`

This validator can be used by installing the prerelease version of the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation` NuGet package.

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms/validation?view=aspnetcore-8.0#nested-models-collection-types-and-complex-types).

> Blazor provides support for validating form input using data
> annotations with the built-in DataAnnotationsValidator. However, the
> DataAnnotationsValidator only validates top-level properties of the
> model bound to the form that aren't collection- or complex-type
> properties.
>
> To validate the bound model's entire object graph, including
> collection- and complex-type properties, use the
> ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator provided by the experimental
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation package

#### Edit

Thanks to MrC aka Shaun Curtis for making it clear in the comments that the package I have referenced was last updated in 2020 and should probably not be used for new projects that you want to maintain over future releases of .NET.

One thing to bear in mind is that if the approach you want to take doesn't seem to be well-supported, it might be worth re-thinking your approach.

Comment: I know this is still referred to in MS Docs, but it's "Pre-Release" and the last Nuget package [https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation] update date [Last updated 29/04/2020] doesn't fill me with expectation that it's going to get updated and released.  The alternative is to think differently about how you validate and use Fluent Validations - see https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/blazor.html

Comment: I did mention that it was pre-release in my answer, but thanks for making it clearer that it's basically unsupported. If I were to offer my opinion I would say that form models should be kept flat, but that kind of answer then verges more into the realm of opinion rather than solving the problem at hand. Thanks also to posting a link to alternative approaches - could you provide an answer using the approach you think best fits the question?

Comment: Kurt - thanks.  I have a bad feeling that it's been dropped.  I have a very different approach to core data management and the data pipeline. Flat value object models , tight Flux based object mutation and "aggregates" to deal with complex entities like shopping carts.  Way beyond the scope of an SO answer.

Comment: Agreed. One for the blog methinks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have a complex object. In this case it's relatively easy to flatten out.

In the code below I've created an edit context from the object and moved the validation to that object.  Create an instance of `StudentEditContext` in the edit form and then submit `StudentEditContext.AsStudent` back into the data pipeline to persist it.

```cs
public class Student
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public Phone Phone { get; set; } = new();
}

public class Phone
{
    public string? Number { get; set; }
}

public class StudentEditContext
{
    [Required] public string? Name { get; set; }

    [Required] public string? Number { get; set; }

    public StudentEditContext(Student student)
    {
        this.Name = student.Name;
        this.Number = student.Phone.Number;
    }

    public Student AsStudent => new()
    {
        Name = this.Name,
        Phone = new() { Number = this.Number },
    };
}
```

That being said, I'm guessing you've simplified your requirement and your object isn't so simple to deal with.

While it's relatively easy to get such a data object from the data domain [EF makes it simple], dealing with it safely and properly in the core business domain is far more complex.  An explanation of how to construct and use aggregate objects is far too complex a subject for an SO answer.